# iFrames and hyperlinks, click a link in one iFrame to open in another

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, hyperlink

So, lets say there are two iframes, ifra0 and ifra1. Hyperlinks in ifra0 are fun to click but it would be nice to just have them open in ifra1 instead of a new tab or window. How can I accomplish this using Javascript? I do not have control over the content of these pages.

The page with the iframes is hosted on my computer, the iframes are webpages on the Internet.

EDIT: HTML4 Transitional would be okay.

Comment: I entered your title in google, and the first result is your answer. Did you google it? http://www.angelfire.com/nm/thehtmlsource/tutors/frames/targetframe.html

Comment: The problem is I don't have control of the content of the webpages. I can't change the links on the pages from the Internet I don't control right?

Comment: Alright, that wasn't in your question before. You indeed can't change it.

Comment: Probably should have clarified. Am I asking the impossible here?

Comment: not sure about it. As far as I know you can't do it

Answer (score 0):

Frames can communicate using `postMessage()` in co-operative Javascripts.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

- The Javascript must be loaded in every `<iframe>`
- Older browsers may not be supported
- http://ajaxian.com/archives/cross-window-messaging-with-html-5-postmessage
- Catch click() event in one IFRAME
- Convert it to postMessage() message
- Post it to the target frame
- Target frame parses the message and performs window.location change based on the message payload

Though I am not sure whether the top frame hosting two iframes must be co-operating or not.